How Can I remove my account?
How can I remove my account? 
I found another more suitable forum for my questions and I would like to remove this one.

P.s. your question seemed to be on topic here, but we do expect a minimum amount of initial research when asking questions on this site. With a minimal amount of edits (as commented on) your question would be well-received.

It is a bit hidden away, but the help center provides the information you are looking for:
How do I delete my account?

It seemed to have been a helpful answer, given the state of the account :) +1
